# Simple HTML parser get link between td tag

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

HTML structure:

```
<tr>
<td><div class="img ico-networking" title="Tinklalapis"></div></td>
<td>Tinklalapis</td>
<td>
<a href="http://www.google.lt" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://www.servit.lt</a>                                                      <a title="Informacija apie svetainę servit.lt" href="http://www.ooo.lt/svetaine/google.lt" class="infoAboutSite iconInfo" target="_blank"></a>                                                                                              <a title="Įmonės svetainė servit.lt" href="google.com" class="infoAboutSite siteScreenshot iconWww" target="_blank"></a>                                            </td>
</tr>
```

My PHP selector: `$tr->children[2]->find('a',0)->href;`

I'm getting empty string, what is wrong with my selector ?

Comment: Can't you use [DOM](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran it will be hard to rewrite all project :(

Comment: So are you using this [parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran yes.

Comment: You have to provide more details. Where the code of `$tr` variable initialzation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code that helps you

```
<?php
$help1 = '<tr>
<td><div class="img ico-networking" title="Tinklalapis"></div></td>
<td>Tinklalapis</td>
<td>
<a href="http://www.google.lt" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://www.servit.lt</a>                                                      <a title="Informacija apie svetainę servit.lt" href="http://www.ooo.lt/svetaine/google.lt" class="infoAboutSite iconInfo" target="_blank"></a>                                                                                              <a title="Įmonės svetainė servit.lt" href="google.com" class="infoAboutSite siteScreenshot iconWww" target="_blank"></a>                                            </td>
</tr>';
include "simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php";
$help2 = str_get_html($help1);
echo $help2->find('a',0)->href ;

?>
```